# How to make a program running multiple instances of another app

Tags: c#, windows

my problem is to use parallelism to speed-up the extraction of tiles from a bigtiff file. I use Tifflibrary which seems to be the only library allowing tile extraction from bigtiff. It works well, but, due to the number of tiles and tiff file size, I would like to extract tiles using more than one task. What I noticed is that, if I use a single App, with several tasks, each of them extracting a tile, i get the same tile from all tasks. Each task contains its own decoder object and related stuff. Nevertheless, of course, each task calls same dll (Tifflibrary.dll). For this reason I think that the result obtained is always the same (actually the last task one). From my results, I think that, in such situation, there is no solution. Then I have developed a console App which produces a tile. It depends on various dlls, besides the Tifflibrary.dll. The question is now: may I create a "master" app that runs various instances of this console App simultaneusly?
To be clearer I attach some code, probably not working, just to explain better. This is the first idea, one App with several tasks.
First some globals:

```
    int SizeTileX = 2048, SizeTileY = 2048;
    int OriWid, OriHei; // big tiff width/height
    int nTasks = 3; // how many parallel tasks
    string Origin;  // name of the tiff file

    List<string> FileList = new List<string>();  // names of the tiles
    List<Point> Posiz = new List<Point>();       // positions of the tiles in the BigTiff
    List<Point> PointList = new List<Point>();   // positions of the tiles in the tiled result
    List<byte[]> arrayList = new List<byte[]>(); // in this list I (would like to) store the decoded result
    List<Task> tasks; // tasks are stored in a List
```

Then I have the Task creation:

```
    public void CreateTasks(int ini) // ini is just an initial number. 
    {
        tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nTasks; i++)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[SizeTileX * SizeTileY * 3];
            Task task = new Task(() => MakeTile( PointList.ElementAt(ini + i).X, PointList.ElementAt(ini + i).Y, bytes));
            
            tasks.Add(task); // store in List

            arrayList.Add(bytes); // store in List
        }
    }
```

And the "Task function":

```
    public void MakeTile(int px, int py,byte[] bytes)
    {
        TiffFileReader tiff;
        TiffImageFileDirectory ifd;
        TiffImageDecoder decoder;
        TiffMemoryPixelBuffer<TiffRgb24> pixelBuffer;
        TiffRgb24[] pixels;

        tiff = TiffFileReader.Open(Origin); // origin is global, just the name of the source Tiff
        ifd = tiff.ReadImageFileDirectory();
        decoder = tiff.CreateImageDecoder(ifd);

        pixels = new TiffRgb24[SizeTileX * SizeTileY];
        pixelBuffer = new TiffMemoryPixelBuffer<TiffRgb24>(pixels, SizeTileX, SizeTileY, writable: true);

        // Read a sub-region starting from (px, py).
        decoder.Decode(new TiffPoint(px, py), pixelBuffer); // decodes the region

        for (int i = 0, j; i < pixels.Length; i++) // trasports the decoded result to byte[]
        {
                TiffRgb24 p = pixels.ElementAt(i);
                j = i * 3;
                bytes[j] = p.B;
                bytes[j + 1] =  p.R;
                bytes[j + 2] =  p.G;
        }

    }
```

And execution of the tasks:

```
public void Esegui()
    {
            CreateTasks(0);

            foreach (Task t in tasks)
            {
                t.Start();
            }
            
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            // after this I expect to have nTasks byte[] arrays
            // in fact arrayList is  list of byte[] arrays         
            // created in CreateTasks
            // .. here I get the various byte[] and save to disk
            // .. but, as I said, they have all same content

            foreach (Task task in tasks)
            {
                task.Dispose();
            }

            tasks.Clear();
            arrayList.Clear();
      }
```

Comment: Could you share some code samples (cut out the irrelevant bits) to help us understand what you’re talking about?

Comment: I updated the question, showing first idea of using various tasks to simultaneously decode different parts of the bigtiff. As, I wrote, I am "quite" sure that, despite I declared a decoder inside the Task Function, (so, in theory, they should be different), actually only one is working. After this, I am looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Btw I found the answer to my question: I have done a "caller" program, in this case in VisualStudio C++, and I repeatedly call the C# console program. I used Createprocess in the C++ caller, to call the C# executable. It works, provided that some delay is left between successive. As a matter of fact, if I Create some processes in a loop, for example of 6, only the last Process is executed. Empirically I added a delay of one second, and things are resolved.
Here is the caller:

```
void Caller()
{
STARTUPINFO si; 
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;

char NomeExe[128];
CString Origin = "d:\\Ortofoto\\bigfile.tif";// 
int SizeTileX = 2048, SizeTileY = 2048;
int px = 155000, py = 62000; // extraction positions
CString TileName,LogName; // names of tile extracted and info log

for (int nclicks = 0; nclicks < 6; nclicks++)
{
    TileName.Format("teste%d.jpg", nclicks); // name of output changes

    px += nclicks * SizeTileX; // for testing, I move extraction point horizontally
    // C# console App is MakeTile.exe
    strcpy(NomeExe, "D:\\MakeTile\\MakeTile\\bin\\Release\\MakeTile.exe"); 
    
    // not knowing how to pass parameters, I simply use a txt file to exchange data
    // The file is read by MakeTile.exe
    FILE* fx = fopen("MakeTiles\\ParmsTiling.txt", "wt");
    fprintf(fx, "%s\n", Origin);
    fprintf(fx, "%ld\n", SizeTileX);
    fprintf(fx, "%ld\n", SizeTileY);
    fprintf(fx, "%ld\n", px);
    fprintf(fx, "%ld\n", py);
    fprintf(fx, "%s\n", TileName);
    fclose(fx);

    if (!CreateProcess(NomeExe,          
        "",               // Command line. 
        NULL,             // Process handle not inheritable. 
        NULL,             // Thread handle not inheritable. 
        FALSE,            // Set handle inheritance to FALSE. 
        0,                // No creation flags. 
        NULL,             // Use parent's environment block. 
        NULL,             // Use parent's starting directory. 
        &si,              // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
        &pi)             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
        )
    {
        return;
    }
    Sleep(1000); // whithout this delay (or less, I didn't try) the Processes are not correctly created
 }
}
```

Any further comment is welcome. Thanks for attention.